# "Uncaught Syntax Error : Unexpected token < " when using jQuery's append

Tags: jquery, append

Here is a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9vWkJ/) of my problem.

This jquery snippet adds 3 divs once a click event is fired. However, the console says "Uncaught Syntax Error : Unexpected token < ".

script

```
$('#e16').on('click', function(){
 $(this).append("<div id='e17' class='kim2bb'>Alcohol 0.2+</div>
                 <div id='e18' class='kim2bb'>Alcohol 1.0~2.0</div>
                 <div id='e19' class='kim2bb'>Alcohol 0.05~1.0</div>");
});
```

html

```
<div id="e16" class="kim2bb">Drunken Drive</div>
```

Comment: The problem is from line breaks after your `</div>` Remove them and you will see that the code runs just fine. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dDFDx/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a string broken over multiple lines:

```
$(this).append("<div id='e17' class='kim2bb'>Alcohol 0.2+</div>" +
                "<div id='e18' class='kim2bb'>Alcohol 1.0~2.0</div>" +
                "<div id='e19' class='kim2bb'>Alcohol 0.05~1.0</div>");
```

Comment: this one is correct, thanks.

Comment: You were faster :( So atleast maybe I get upvote :)

Comment: jquery doesn't like multiple spaces?

Comment: @DeckTrout - In essence, what you did was this: `$(this).append("<div id='e17' class='kim2bb'>Alcohol 0.2+</div>;<div id='e18' class='kim2bb'>Alcohol 1.0~2.0</div>;<div id='e19' class='kim2bb'>Alcohol 0.05~1.0</div>");` And the exception was thrown when it encountered `<` on line 2 of this snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(this).append("<div id='e17' class='kim2bb'>Alcohol 0.2+</div>" +
                        "<div id='e18' class='kim2bb'>Alcohol 1.0~2.0</div>" + 
                        "<div id='e19' class='kim2bb'>Alcohol 0.05~1.0</div>");
```

Pluses on end of line are important so just copy it and try.